# Separation and connected subset proof ploblem

Tags: real-analysis

If the sets $A$ and $B$ form a separation of a metric space $M$, and if $N$ is a connected subset of $M$, then $N$ lies entirely within either $A$ and $B$.

This is my real analysis book problem, but there is no solution given.

How can I prove that?

Comment: $N \cap A$ and $N \cap B$ would otherwise form a separation of $N$.

Answer (score 0):

> Two Definitions
>
> Disconnected set: $N$ is disconnected if there exist two disjoint non-empty open sets $A$ and $B$ such that $N = A \cup B$
>
> Seperation of a set: Two sets $A,B\subseteq X$ is said to separate $X$ iif $1)A,B \neq \emptyset$, $2) A,B $ relatively open in $X$, $3) A \cap B = \emptyset$,$4)A \cup B = X$

*Proof*. $N$ is connected in $M$, thus there is no disjoint non-empty open sets $A$ and $B$, such that $N = A \cup B$.

Since $A$ and $B$ is a separation of $M$, and $N$ is a subset of $M$, we have $N \cap A$ and $N \cap B$ could not both be $\emptyset$.

And meanwhile, by the first paragraph of the proof, it is also not true that they are both non-empty sets (otherwise $N$ is disconnection, because we find two sets $A$ and $B$)

We are done.